# Node static file server, how to make response work in async callback?

Tags: node.js, http, response

I wrote this function that is triggered when I get a request on my node server, it works perfectly and it sends back a file that automatically starts to download.

```js
function(req, res) {
  // … other code …

  try {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf-8');

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
    });
    res.end(fileContent);
  } catch (err) {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
  }
}
```

Now I want to rewrite it using the `readFile` method so I tried something like this instead:

```js
function(req, res) {
  // … other code …

  fs.readFile(fullPath, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
    });
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

But now it always returns a 404 error, I think the function exits before the response is ready, so it discards the response that happens too late? How can I make it work?

Please don't suggest using third party libraries, as this is not what I'm asking. I want to do this with native modules only.

Thanks in advance.

> using node 10.7.0

Comment: Have you tried logging the error to see what's happening?

Comment: @Paul If the file exists it doesn't enter the if statement (the error is null) and it executes the res.writeHead(200, {…}) etc. But it doesn't return a 200 OK response. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: But you said "Now it always returns a 404 error"

Comment: Ooooh I got it, now that you made me realize that it returns a 404, the problem is actually earlier in the code. I forgot a return inside an if statement! Thanks, I'll update in a moment

Comment: Could you put debug line before `res.writeHead(404);` line to show the err to std? Debug line `console.log(err)`

Comment: @hoangdv Thanks for your interest, but the question is already solved, read the comments and my answer below. The code that I wrote in the original post was correct, the bug was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually earlier in the code, I just forgot to return inside an if statement:

```js
function onRequest(req, res) {    
  // … other code …

  if (someCondition) {
    functionOfTheOriginalPost(req, res);
    return;
    // ^-- This is the return that I forgot so it 
    // was jumping down in the "404" area
  }

  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

Thanks to @Paul that made me think and realize the error.